# How can I manage freelancers effectively in a startup

Tags: management, freelancing, micro-management, agile

The problem is every time I hire someone from freelancing websites, I find it hard to manage the output or the budget.

- example 1 : I hired someone who claimed to be an expert in programming, just to find myself micromanaging him, and in the end... job not done
- example 2 : I hired an expert who charged me $60 for a 5 min job!

Comment: Good, fast, cheap. Pick two.

Comment: If the example 2 expert had been a bit less expert, and done the job but taking an hour to do it, would you have been equally dissatisfied paying $60?

Comment: @Patricia i see your point, but that freelancer is publishing on his profil that his normal rate would be 30$ an hour, before hiring him i thought it will be something complex, maybe him too

Comment: @M'vy I can pick two.. sometimes there are some "expert" as they say, want to charge +10 hours for a job that a true expert will do in a hour, knowing that both true and fake expert will charge you the same amount per hour.

Comment: $30 an hour seems very low for an expert. I got $60 an hour to do some tutoring, and I considered that partly hobby. I would charge a lot more for paid freelance programming.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Finding a causal freelancer on a website like Upworks can be challenging. Everyone will claim they can do the job, my advice:

- Unless you work with a candidate before, always assume the candidate is a novice
- Programming is always and always a cheap skill set, it's all about making functions calling each other logically. You may find a strong programmer, but there is no such thing as expert programming. Everybody who has some computer science experience can compile code. Hard programming skills is high-demand but simple to master. You need someone with good **dedication** and **communication** (soft skills). Narrow your search on those people.
- Offer a fixed price for a small task testing for skills, don't give an hours job unless you're confident.
- Break your job into small pieces, ask your freelancer solve them one by one
- $30 an hour is OK, but please make the job small.

Comment: Hmmm. I've been learning to program almost continuously since 1967, and I am still learning. If you find it that easy, congratulations.

Comment: In what way is it a cheap skillset?

Answer (score 4):

Two problems here.

Firstly a startup in a tech field needs at least one solid dedicated technician. Otherwise it's a marketing driven funding mine. This can be a contractor, but best to use just one proven one.

Secondly don't set jobs without negotiating costs.If you know the cost beforehand and the job is done within the parameters then you'd have nothing to complain about.

With your latter case, most contractors will have a minimum bill. Normally this isn't 5 minutes, so expect any short job to be billed at whatever they have, it's usually an hour or two or much more depending on the level. For some jobs I charge a day minimum whether I finish it in an hour or not... If you don't know then ask.